# bootstrap 3 selectpicker input-lg is overridden

Tags: jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I use bootstrap selectpicker (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

I am trying to enlarge the select box size by doing:

```
<select class="selectpicker input-lg">...</select>
```

If I add "input-lg" to the select input, selectpicker overrides it and the select box isn't resized.

How to overcome this problem?

See http://www.bootply.com/107358# for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `style` option on the selectpicker..

```
style:'btn-lg'
```

http://www.bootply.com/127059

Comment: it works, but i want also btn-default, how do i add btn-default and btn-lg for the same select?

Comment: `style:'btn-default btn-lg'`

Answer (score 5):

If you like to add it inline then use `data-style="input-lg btn-default"` or `data-style="btn-lg btn-default"`

```
<select name="" class="form-control input-lg selectpicker" data-title="Select Time" data-style="input-lg btn-default">...</select>
```